# How is the Bloch equation derived?

Tags: electronic-structure, derivations

I am reading a [textbook](https://books.google.ca/books?hl=en&lr=&id=eUgWDAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=relativistic+many-body+theory+Ingvar&ots=ZVHfhrCegD&sig=-lvlCZKiHicm9zdNBmn7OYOYNq4&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=relativistic%20many-body%20theory%20Ingvar&f=false) on many-electron theory, which gives a Bloch equation in its generalized form:

$$\tag{1}
[\Omega,H_0]P=Q(V\Omega-\Omega V_{eff})P,
$$

where $P$ denotes the projection from exact state to a model state:

$$\tag{2}
P\mid \psi^{(\alpha)}\rangle=\mid \psi_0^{(\alpha)}\rangle,
$$

and $\Omega$ denotes a mapping from the model state to the exact state:

$$\tag{3}
\Omega\mid \psi_0^{(\alpha)}\rangle=\mid \psi^{(\alpha)}\rangle,
$$

and $Q=1-P$.

The textbook I use has an ambiguous derivation of the Bloch equation with many steps skipped. I would appreciation if someone could explain to me how it is derived.

It's eq. 55 on pg 21 of the textbook.

Comment: It would be helpful for others if you cite the textbook from which you got the equation.

Comment: +1. But I agree with Rashid. This is not the notation in which Bloch equations are typically written. I personally wouldn't even call this the Bloch equation, unless there's something I'm missing, which is probably the case, since without the textbook I can't see the context.

Comment: Unfortunately I can see everything up to pg 20, and everything from pg 22 onwards, but pg 21 says "image not available".

Comment: Really? That is weird. I can see up to page 30?@NikeDattani

Comment: @PaulieBao unfortunately, google book previews, like Google searches, tend to be customized to the particular user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They start with the time-independent Schrödinger equation:

$$\tag{1}
H|\psi^\alpha\rangle  = E^\alpha |\psi^\alpha\rangle.
$$

Then they define $|\psi_0^\alpha\rangle$ to be what they call a "model state", which is an approximation to the true state $|\psi^\alpha\rangle$ but more easily accessible, and is related to the true state by a Møller operator  $\Omega$, and to the true energy $E^\alpha$ by $H_{\textrm{eff}}$:

$$\tag{2}
|\psi^\alpha\rangle \equiv \Omega |\psi_0^\alpha\rangle ~~~, ~~~ H_{\textrm{eff}}|\psi_0^\alpha\rangle\equiv E^\alpha |\psi_0^\alpha\rangle.
$$

We can multiply the second part of Eq 2 by $\Omega$ on both sides of the equation, then re-write it using the first part of Eq 2:

\begin{alignat}{2}
\tag{3}
\Omega H_{\textrm{eff}}|\psi_0^\alpha\rangle &= E^\alpha |\psi^\alpha\rangle.
\end{alignat}

Likewise we can simply substitute the first part of Eq 2 into Eq 1 and get:

\begin{alignat}{3}
\tag{4}
 H \Omega |\psi_0^\alpha\rangle &= E^\alpha |\psi^\alpha\rangle.
\end{alignat}

Since the right-side of Eqs 3 and 4 are the same, we can equate the left sides too:

\begin{alignat}{3}
\tag{5}
\Omega H_{\textrm{eff}}|\psi_0^\alpha\rangle  &=  H \Omega |\psi_0^\alpha\rangle.
\end{alignat}

Then they say that since Eq 5 applies for all model states (*i.e.* all values of $\alpha$) we can replace $|\psi_0^\alpha\rangle$ by $P$:

\begin{alignat}{3}
\tag{6}
\Omega H_{\textrm{eff}}P  &=  H \Omega P.
\end{alignat}

By partitioning $H=H_0 + V$ we get:

\begin{alignat}{3}
\tag{6}
\Omega H_{\textrm{eff}}P  &=  H_0 \Omega P + V \Omega P.
\end{alignat}

What happens next is not explained in the text, but they get:

\begin{alignat}{3}
\tag{7}
H_{\textrm{eff}}  &=  PH_0  P + PV \Omega P.
\end{alignat}

To get the last term, I would left-multiply all terms by $P$, but something else must have happened for the two other terms to be the way they are. Anyway, they make the second term in Eq. 7 to be defined as $W$ and remove the $H_{\textrm{eff}}$ to get the equation at the beginning of your question. They cite [113,117,124] but with your Google Books link, I can't see pages 61 to 405 and it seems the bibliography is at the end (in those missing pages). Do you happen to know what [113,117,124] are?

Anyway, they finally say that in the case where all model states have the same energy $E_0$, we get the original Bloch equation that they say was derived in the late 1950s by the French nuclear physicist ***Claude Bloch***, (*not* the much more famous Bloch equation first presented in 1948 by the Swiss-American physicist ***Felix Bloch*** and his PhD student Roald Wangsness):

$$\tag{8}
\left(E_0 - H_0  \right)\Omega P = V \Omega P  - \Omega W.
$$

---

**Edit:** After a lot more searching I have found that the author of that book explained this same derivation in a lot more detail in [this 1974 paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3700/7/18/010). Pay attention to what he says about $P$ and $\Omega$ not being "true" inverses of each other, and what happens when you combine them. It is also quite amazing that the notation is almost the same in the [original 1958 paper of Claude Bloch](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0029558258901160?via%3Dihub). The paper is in French, but it's not too hard to follow the equations (he shows quite a lot of steps!).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Actually I follow all the step of derivation up to eq(6) (second eq(6)) but get stuck from equation 6 to equation 7. I will read in details on the reference .

Comment: Actually, I manage to prove that if the model space is complete degenerate with a single energy $E_0$, my equation(1) will be reduce to the original form of Bloch equation (your equation 8)